# Executing C++ with Armadillo in PHP script

Tags: php, c++, apache, armadillo

My colleague and I are working on a project together. We have a compiled C++ program which we execute from a PHP script, returning the C++ data to an array. Nothing weird about that. (We are running on Ubuntu, Apache, locally), two different machines.

```
exec("./program", $array);
```

He has just given me the compiled program for me to implement it to my PHP code. Nothing has gone wrong, it works as expected.

The weird thing about this is that when he with my PHP code, tries to execute the program, it doesn't work IF Armadillo is included when he compiles the program. So he tried making a simple Hello World program, including and not including Armadillo. It's still the same. Although, it works either way if he executes it via the terminal which makes me believe it's something with Apache/PHP.

I installed everything on its own. PHP version 7.0.22.
He installed the XAMPP version with PHP 7.1.11.

We've looked through php.ini for something useful, but we couldn't find anything stopping the script from executing it.

To sum it up. The program works on my machine whether or not Armadillo is included. It doesn't work for him if Armadillo is included.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Sounds like a dynamic linking problem to me (i.e. the system is not able to find the library binaries). Note: I'm not familiar with Armadillo, so I can't tell for sure.